# Bootstrap NavBar Alignment - Toogle and Collapse with differents alignments

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a Navigation Bar, when collapsed I align to right, but when toggle I want the items centrally aligns.

How can I do that?

HTML

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ian Campelo's Portfolio</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    text-align: right;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  text-align: center;
}
```

CodePen link: http://codepen.io/iancampelo/pen/pjqNYq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css.  [codepen link here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvyjqd)

```
        @media(max-width:768px){
            .navbar-collapse{
                text-align:center;          
            }   
        }
```